# How to match content script with end part of a URL?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, content-script

I am working on a chrome extension. I want to match end part of URL and load content script only the match is successful.
Example is 
https://akp.archive.corn.skuyo.co/2_6_0_11/abc/Account/Login.aspx

So I want to load the content script only if part of a URL contains Account/Login.aspx

I dont want to compare starting point because URL might also be
https://pc-001/2_6_0_11/abc/Account/Login.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution after a bit research. The manifest file will look like this

```json
{  
    "manifest_version": 2,  

    "name": "Autofill Extension",  
    "description": "Autofills assessment data",  
    "version": "1.0",    

    "browser_action": {  
        "default_icon": "icon.png",  
        "default_popup": "popup.html"  
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab","tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/", "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*/abc/Account/Login.aspx*"],
            "js": ["jquery.js", "content_script.js","core.js" ]
        }
    ]
}
```